# How to insert image in message body

Tags: c#, html

```
message.Body = "Dear " + myds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("C_Name").ToString() 
+ " <br /> <br /> Your Registrtion is Successfull...<br/><br/>
<table  border='4'><tr><td>Name = " 
+ myds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("C_Name").ToString() 
+ " </td><td> Pax= " 
+ myds.Tables[1].Rows[0].Field<int>("pax").ToString() 
+ "</td> </tr><tr><td>Della Adventure,Kunegao,Lonavala</td><td>CheckIn Date= " 
+ myds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("Checkin_date").ToString() 
+ "</td></tr></table>";
```

This is my code and I want to add image in the message body.

Comment: Where you need the image?

Comment: A string.format would make that way more readable/maintainable

Comment: You might need to read [How to improve string concatenation performance](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822)

Comment: Is the image in a binary format, or is it hosted on a webserver?

Comment: Actuly i want to send a ticket like structure to the customer...for dat m adding images i.e it is my messege will look like ticket...for eg. ticket like bookmyshow tiket when we book the ticket...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image tag to display the image in your body of the mail.

Instead of storing the image in to DB refer the image path. Do the following steps

1. Just upload the image in to you're server location.
2. Store the image path in to DB
3. Get the image path from DB and bind it to image source.

For Example.

```
 <img height="" width="" border="0" alt="" src="https://www.xyz.com/images/123.jpg"></img>
```

Bindling the image URL

```
<tr><td> <img height="" width="" border="0" alt=" src="+ myds.Tables[1].Rows[0].Field<string>("imageurl").ToString() + "></img></td> </tr>
```

Your entire code could be..

```
message.Body = "Dear " + myds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("C_Name").ToString() + " <br /> <br /> Your Registrtion is Successfull...<br/><br/><table  border='4'><tr><td>Name = " + myds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("C_Name").ToString() + " </td><td> Pax= " + myds.Tables[1].Rows[0].Field<int>("pax").ToString() + "</td> </tr>
**<tr><td> <img height="" width="" border="0" alt=" src="+ myds.Tables[1].Rows[0].Field<string>("imageurl").ToString() + "></img></td> </tr>**
<tr><td>Della Adventure,Kunegao,Lonavala</td><td>CheckIn Date= " + myds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("Checkin_date").ToString() + "</td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your creating the inline HTML for message body. In this case you can generate  the base64 string for image and then embed the image source for image tag with base64 string like below -

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..."/>
```

Comment: Not every client supports it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070196/what-is-data-uri-support-like-in-major-email-client-software

Comment: Thanks Kees C. Bakker. @user2862920, please rethink about your strategy on using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use html template to send image in the mail body

Please go through the following links.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-and-send-HTML-Formatted-Emails-in-ASP.Net-using-C-and-VB.Net.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16730/Embed-image-in-Email-ASP-NET-C

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-send-mail-with-images-using.html