# Email signatures - embedded or linked images?

Tags: html

In the middle of creating some HTML email signatures for our company. Every so often I get "mime-attachment.png" instead of the actual image on some replies to my emails. At the moment they are linked like the following:

```
<img src="http://url/image1.png">
```

Should embedding my images into the signature? If so how would I do this? I see some examples that look like this, but not sure how to link the cid to the image:

```
<img src="cid:My-Image-Identifier">
```

Comment: Personally, I think including any images in the signature is a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use DATA URI scheme. [Wikipedia has an simple example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Just encode your picture with base64 and replace the part between `base64,` and the first `"`.

Comment: Is it true that most clients don't display this type of signature properly?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, works fine if I open the signature in a web browser but does not work in our email client - IBM Lotus Notes 8.5 It was supported in version 8.0 but looks like it's been dropped.

This question also suggests that Lotus Notes 8.5 does not support it [What is Data URI support like in major email client software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070196/what-is-data-uri-support-like-in-major-email-client-software)

Are there alternatives?