# Embedded image in HTML not appearing in outlook renderer

Tags: c#, html, outlook

I am sending an email which contains within an HTML document the following

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/*base64-data-string here*/" />
```

If I save the source of the email and view in a browser, I see the image fine. However in the outlook preview panel it just shows as the invalid or no-image thumbnail and doesnt load the image.

I can see from googling around that embedded images is not supported in Outlook. How else can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send inline image in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many e-mail clients don't accept images in data uris. This is nothing new. If supporting Outlook specifically is what you're after, I'd go with linking to CIDs and including images as new parts of your multipart e-mail.

See also these threads:

- [What is Data URI support like in major email client software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070196/what-is-data-uri-support-like-in-major-email-client-software)
- [Data URI in Outlook](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7ae64d7d-3af6-4b21-aae8-122f4797200c)
- [How to Embed Images in Your Emails](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/)