# E-mail doesn't display base64 image using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Guys I am stuck in displaying a base64 image in a HTML e-mail using handlebars.js.

```
    //imageURL : data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==
    <img id="img" class="someClass" src="{{imageURL}}" >
```

I don't know how to display a image using handlebars. Kindly help me to move further.

Comment: The imageURL is base64 text? Because then you can use `src="data:image/png;base64, {{imageURL}}"`

Comment: No that's not simple text ,imageurl contain full base64 string

Comment: If you hard-code the imageURL in the img tag, does it show? 
Also, what is the outputted HTML? (right-click + inspect element)

Comment: Ya when i hot-code it it's showing

Comment: If you use it with `{{imageURL}}` what does it show in the browser dev tools (F12)?

Comment: am sending a image to mail as a html template using handlebar so i can't use dev tools

Answer (score 1):

Your template is already correct. If you want an example using your template see the following code:

```js
var source = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {
  imageURL: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
};
var html = template(context);

document.getElementById("template").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div id="template">
  <img id="img" class="someClass" src="{{imageURL}}" >
</div>
```

**Update:** The author didn't specify that the template was used in a e-mail. As said in the comments it is possible that the e-mail client doesn't support base64 images. For a more detailed answer about this, check the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9330720/2540618.

Comment: when its send to mail as a html template it does not work,actually am trying to send a image to mail as a html template using handlebar

Comment: Some e-mail clients wont support this. See the following answer on a different question on StackOverflow which e-mail clients support Image URI's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9330720/2540618

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **SafeString** from Handlebars like this:

```
import { SafeString } from 'handlebars'

const imageURL = new SafeString('data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACw...')

// In your template
<img id="img" class="someClass" src="{{imageURL}}" >
```