# Attach a file with contentId from inside an email Layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

### What I have

In my Controller (CakePHP 3.8):

```
$email = new \Cake\Mailer\Email();
$email
    ->emailFormat('html')
    ->setLayout('mylayout')
    ->setTo($to)
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->addAttachments([
        'logo.png' => [
            'file' => $logoImage,
            'mimetype' => mime_content_type($logoImage),
            'contentId' => 'mylogo'
        ]
    ])
    ->send($message);
```

And then in `src/Template/Layout/Email/html/mylayout.ctp`:

```
<img src="cid:mylogo">
```

That works.

### What I want

I want to embed that image from within the Layout file.

- So I don't have to repeat `->addAttachments()` every time I'm sending an e-mail
- If I replace the image I can do it in the Layout only once
- If I use another Layout that doesn't need the image, it won't be attached and sent

Using `contentId` looks like an option. But how do I do it from inside the Layout?

### What I tried

- Sending the image as data/uri, but [that didn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070196/what-is-data-uri-support-like-in-major-email-client-software)
- Searching for some `Cake\Mailer` instance under `$this` when in Layout, but couldn't find any

Comment: Adding attachments seems kinda out of scope for the view layer, you should probably look into using [**reusable mailers**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails) instead.

Comment: @ndm, thanks. [The reusable emails example](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-reusable-emails) creates *a Mailer that contains user-related emails*, so there must be a reason for that separation. Please advise, if I create a one big Mailer reused for all emails, users and not, would it break some CakePHP pattern or convention that I may not be knowing/thinking about?