# How to insert to mailmessage a image from database

Tags: .net, vb.net, sendmail

I have an image stored in sql server.  I want to retrieve the image and place it in a MailMessage object, not as an attachment file, but as part of the html body.

I found many samples using local image file, but I have not found any using an image from a database.

Anyone know how I can do this in vb.net?

Thank you in advance!

Javier

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261956/how-to-embed-an-image-stream-to-mailmessage.  Though it doesn't pull the image from the database it does show you how to embed an image that does not come from a local filepath.  You can combine this code with code to retrieve the image from the database into a memory stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the image from the database as a [LinkedResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.linkedresource.aspx).
When you retrieve the image as bytes from the database, you can add the LinkedResource using a stream; by creating a memorystream from the bytes.

Code in C#, but I think you should be able to convert this to VB.Net

```
var view = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, "text/html");
var resource = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(bytes), mime);
resource.ContentId = image.Name;
view.LinkedResources.Add(resource);
_message.AlternateViews.Add(view);
```

Comment: Do you know why in gmail account this images doesn't show?, in outlook, with an other internet mail account configured, the image is shown correctly?... I try to insert image as attachment, in this case, outlook show the image correctly too, but in gmail show as an attachment, doesn't show in html body ...

Answer (score 0):

you have to include the image in the htmlbody with an imagetag: `<img src="cid:myuniqueid" alt="img" />`

By adding a LinkedResource you can include the image to the message. But you need to create a link between html body and the image. this is the "cid:myuniqueid" from the html body. The value of cid must be equal to the value of the ContentID Property of the LinkedResource Object.

Here is an example:

```vb
     '** Create MailMessage Object
     Dim message As New MailMessage()

     '** Create HTML view
     Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlbody, System.Text.Encoding.Default, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)

     '** Create resource for the image
     Dim lr As New LinkedResource(objStream)

     '** Set the contentid for the image resource
     lr.ContentId = "myuniqueid"

     '** Link image resource and htmlview together
     htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(lr)

     '** Add view to MailMessage Object
     message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
```

Comment: What is "objStream" in your code?, could you insert the define statement?