# No embedded images in email

Tags: c#, .net, email, html-email

I try to send email with embedded images. Images are going from `List<Bitmap>` and I am sure they are there 100%.

Somehow when I get email I don't see any images at all and HTML looks like

```
<img alt="" hspace="0" src="http://image0" align="baseline" border="0">
<br />

<img alt="" hspace="0" src="http://image1" align="baseline" border="0">
<br />
```

Any clue?

C# is like

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();

var msg = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("support@mysite.com", "mysite.com Support"),
                                new MailAddress(email, email));
msg.Subject = "No worries, man";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
var bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count; i++)
   bodyBuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("<img alt=\"\" hspace='0' src='cid:image{0}' align='baseline' border='0'><br />",i));
var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyBuilder.ToString(), null, "text/html");

var index = 0;
foreach (var page in pages) // where page is List<Bitmap>
{
   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   page.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

   var imagelink = new LinkedResource(memoryStream, "image/png");
   imagelink.ContentId = string.Format("image{0}", index); 
   imagelink.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;

   htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink);
   index++;
}

msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

try
{
    smtp.Send(msg);
    return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);

   return Json("false", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: The html src tag on those `img` elements don't look right.

Comment: @gwin003 ... well... how it should be in case of embedded images then? Could u suggest pls?

Comment: @MichaelTodd Sorry ... Everything is in code, could you take a look at that pls?

Comment: mm...why you dont set encode type in you htmlview ? like  

   AlternateView htmlView =        AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(bodyBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

Comment: When you debug, at what point does the string in the `img src` change from `cid:` to `http:`?

Comment: @Metropolitan Have you seen this example about 1/4 down the page? http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/95_Sending_Email_using_C__and_ASPNet_20.aspx

Comment: @gwin003 Yes I did. I have used it but in fact I use MemoryStream class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys

I found the awesome solution here

[How to embed an Image Stream to MailMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261956/how-to-embed-an-image-stream-to-mailmessage/9239880#9239880)

Here is correct code:

```
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
Byte [] ba = (Byte[]) ic.ConvertTo(page,typeof(Byte[]));
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ba);
page.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```