# How To embed image in email not from external file?

Tags: c#, image, email, embed, attachment

so I know this is a widely discussed subject, nonetheless amongst all the threads i've read i haven't found a solution yet, hence the new topic

so basically i have a c# winform app to create reports on my team's activity
of course i'd like to send these reports by mail

the thing is all the threads i've read/tried out discuss embedding an image FROM AN EXTERNAL FILE (bmp, gif, jpeg)

what i've been trying to do is to embed an image from a runtime graphic chart component

for example what i can do is capture the chart to a bmp and stream it to windows clipboard then paste into a mail body

of course the objective is to have this automatically, but i can't find anywhere how to include my runtime chart in a mail body.

the major issue i have encountered is everytime i try to add a stream to a linked ressource item i get that frustrating GDI++ error

here is my latest test :

```
           string htmlBody = "<html><body><p>report</p>";

            AlternateView view = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

            foreach (ChartModuleModel item in _checkedListBox.CheckedItems)

            {

                string itemStr = item.ToString();

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                item.Chart().SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);

                LinkedResource res =

                    new LinkedResource(ms, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

                res.ContentId = itemStr;

                view.LinkedResources.Add(res);

                htmlBody += "<p>chart : " + itemStr + "</p>";

                htmlBody += "<img src=\"cid:" + itemStr + "\">";

            }



            htmlBody += "</body></html>";

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.AlternateViews.Add(view);

            mail.From = new MailAddress(_mailToTextBox.Text);

            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(_mailToTextBox.Text));

            mail.Subject = _mailSubjectTextBox.Text;



            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            client.Port = 25;

            client.Host = "smtp-goss.int.world.socgen";

            client.Send(mail);
```

Thanks to you all for your help,

crazy

Comment: take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6279793/1783240

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the only way to embed an image in email is with Base64 encoding. [This post will get you started](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email) - it also links to additional resources.

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email) is for php, but may also help.