# base64 not being decoded in gmail

Tags: html, email, base64

To avoid unloaded images, for my inline html-mail I've encoded all images (4 actual images and 6 empty gif for spacing) to base64 strings,. Works pretty fine how-ever gmail refuses to decode these back into images.
I've done some pretty extensive investigation but came up empty handed.

What about cid:url?

Answer (score 34):

Gmail Web Client does support embedded images

See my answer to [Base64 images to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279523/base64-images-to-gmail/12786336#12786336)

Comment: If you using nodemailer, check the solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946783/gmail-blocking-small-embedded-inline-images-in-email-template/68532260#68532260)

Answer (score 15):

Gmail doesn't anymore.

Apple mail is one of the few that still does. So unless you plan on sending only to apple owners, you may want to find another way to do that

For example, adding another part with your base64 image:
Content-Type: image/png; name="imagename.png"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="imagename.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Comment: It still works on my Gmail accounts the classic way: <img src="data:image/png;base64..."/>. Both desktop and mobile apps.

Comment: @Jeremy, do you know how recent exactly is this? I just recently got complaints about this from clients, and I didn't do any code change in the mailing subsystem since last summer. I cannot decide if this is something on my end. Outlook web mail client also doesn't display the base64 inlined image.

Comment: I tested it. "data:image/png;base64" just doesn't work for GMail anymore. You need to use cid and inline attachments instead

Comment: Can you show us how to use cid and inline attachment, perhaps in a new answer? Thanks