# SendGrid Image Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send an email via Sendgrid using the following code. The email has an image which I am trying to send.

```
        var client = new SendGridClient("MYAPIKEY");
        var from = new EmailAddress("from@from.com");
        var subject = "test";
        var to = new EmailAddress("to@to.com");
        var plainTextContent = "";
        Image s = CreateBitmapImage("Hi");
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        var imageBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(s, typeof(byte[]));
        var b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        var dataUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + b64String;
        var htmlContent = "<img src='" + dataUrl + "' />";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);

        var response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg).Result;
```

Following is what i see in gmail after sending the image.

[image: Result in gmail]

I referred to sendgrid [blogpost](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) for embedding image via base64. Please suggest if I am doing wrong somewhere.

Comment: Could you please specify your .net framework version?

Comment: @Ayberk I am using 4.5.2

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946783/gmail-blocking-small-embedded-inline-images-in-email-template) Please read the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score -1):

Do you check if you have it set？

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();  
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;   
msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
```

If you set，you trying

```
  var dataUrl = "";
  using (System.Drawing.Image s = CreateBitmapImage("Hi"))
  {
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    var imageBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(s, typeof(byte[]));
    var b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    dataUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + b64String;
  }
  var htmlContent = "<img src=\"" + dataUrl + "\" />";
```