# Base64 image in email, does not show in google mail

Tags: email, gmail, base64

I have created a base64 image to be sent via email to the customer on there mobile device
It works in the email app but the gmail app shows a missing image

Is that just google mail blocking data images for security? 
There's no button to show images either

**Code:**

```
    $headers = "From: info@mydomain.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: info@mydomain.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

`$imagedata = file_get_contents("http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php? code=12345&style=68&type=C128B&width=180&height=70&xres=1&font=1");
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
$message ="<img src='data:image/png;base64,$base64'>";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);</pre>`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279523/base64-images-to-gmail/12786336#12786336. Not sure if its still works, most likely will though.

Comment: @Dagon I have added the code and Sam I do not understand how to use that code, as I am very basic with PHP emails

Comment: bares no resemblance to sending email with an embedded image that i have ever seen.

Answer (score 5):

It's google blocking images. Google striped out most inline css and other 'likely' vulnerablilities that cause harm to the end-users' system. Unfortunatly this is the case. However i still think you should never embed your images in e-mail, because you have a lot of mobile users with dataplans. Seems a bit rude.

Answer (score 1):

Google is blocking images. Reference: [2013 test from Campaign Monitor on Embedded image support in HTML email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email).