# base64 image code not work in gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, base64, zend-mail

I use zend_mail and render smarty tpl with email template. I try to send logo in email message (code using base64):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAO8AAAA1CAYAAACp1bzwAAAACXBIWXMAAA7CAAAOwgE...
```

This doesn't work in gmail, the image is still hidden...

I found this:
[Base64 images to gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279523/base64-images-to-gmail)
but I don't know how to load headers, i tried use

```
$mail->addHeader(...);
```

but it doesn't bring any effect, how can i solve this problem to code logo in base64 to work in any email client ?

Comment: Have you checked your encoding? maybe something is not properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use 
style='display:block;'

Comment: Welcome to SO, if you have an idea of the answer please post it in the comments and do not post an answer if you're not sure this is going to solve the problem. Take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).