# How to display base64 images in gmail?

Tags: image, email, base64, gmail, markdown

I'm sending `base64` encoded images in a markdown newsletter to different email services from a `rich text editor`. Every service renders the images properly except `gmail`. Instead it displays the `base64 string`:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACLQAAAxOCAYAAAD0p7d8AA...
```

The main [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279523/base64-images-to-gmail) regarding this problem does not provide a solution, as can be seen in the comments of the accepted answer.

How does one display images from a `data string` in gmail? Is it possible to insert a transformation layer to make it work? (I can't believe gmail doesn't support this after 6 years)

Answer (score 2):

Gmail does not support embedded Base 64 images (see [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/)). I believe this is for general security reasons. You either need to generate your image server side. Or send it as an attachment (like in the other post you mentioned).

Comment: But there are services who send images in text in their emails. The only way to do that is to split the string and insert images from the storage into the string?

Comment: Do you have an example of said services?